# Why I'm not able to close the modal dialog upon click on a hyperlink which is present on the same modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've a following HTML code of bootstrap modal :

```
<div style="display: block; padding-right: 13px;" id="myModal-event" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
  <!-- <div role="document" class="modal-dialog"> -->
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;"> 

    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog event-planner">
<div class="modal-content">
  <!-- <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="event-title">
        NewDemoEvent5
        <input name="hid_event_id" id="hid_event_id" value="501" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><img src="http://localhost/CKWEB_28-12-2015/user_ui_files/images/time.png" alt=""> 12:00 pm</li>
          <li><img src="http://localhost/CKWEB_28-12-2015/user_ui_files/images/calender.png" alt=""> Thursday, January 7</li>
                        <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewLocationOnMap();"> <img src="http://localhost/CKWEB_28-12-2015/user_ui_files/images/location.png" alt=""></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewLocationOnMap();">Home Nightclub, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia</a>
            </li>
                            <li><img src="http://localhost/CKWEB_28-12-2015/user_ui_files/images/group_event.png" alt="">Group: Boxing Day</li>
                    <li><button aria-describedby="popover295861" title="" data-original-title="" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover">Edit Event</button><div style="top: 140.717px; left: 104px; display: block;" id="popover295861" class="popover fade right in" role="tooltip"><div style="top: 63.9954%;" class="arrow"></div><h3 style="display: none;" class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
</div></div></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
  <a href="javascript:alert('You clicked me')" class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
</ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" align="right">
          <select name="user_event_responce" id="user_event_responce" class="form-control" style="width:150px;">
            <option value="0">I am..</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Going</option>
            <option value="2">Maybe</option>
            <option value="3">Not Going</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <!--
        <div class="form-group" align="right">
          <select name="event_actions" id="event_actions" class="form-control" style="width:150px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="edit_event">Edit Event</option>
            <option value="invite_members">Invite members</option>
            <option value="delete_event">Delete event</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event-menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a aria-expanded="true" href="#description" data-toggle="tab">Description</a></li>
            <li><a href="#feeds" data-toggle="tab">Feeds</a></li>
            <li><a href="#going" data-toggle="tab">Going</a></li>
            <li><a href="#maybe" data-toggle="tab">Maybe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#notgoing" data-toggle="tab">Not Going</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="description">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          DemoEvent5 is added successfully.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="feeds">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       Work In Progress
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="going">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 no-padding">
          <div class="block"> <img src="http://app.campusknot.com/file/pic/user/1585_100_square.jpg" class="img-event" alt="">
            <span class="author">Sushil Kadam</span>
            <span class="degree"></span> </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="maybe">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


      </div>
    </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="tab-pane" id="notgoing">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


      </div>
    </div>
    </div>    
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to close the above modal on click of a hyperlink **Edit Event** and open up a new modal which is as follows :

```
<div id="myModal-event" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <!-- <div role="document" class="modal-dialog"> -->
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;">
      <!-- <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"> x </span></button> -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> Loading... </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Hos should I do it. I tried many ways but none of them worked for me.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a new id for the second modal so that you'll be able to manage both of them. You could set an id for your Edit Event link so that you could listen an on click event on it.

Thus your link'd looks like:

```
<a href="#" id='edit-event' class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
```

With jQuery you could do:

```
$('#myModal-event').on('click', '#edit-event', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
    $('#modal-2').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Notice that modal-2 is supposed to be the id of your second modal

Comment: Yeah but first modal itself is not getting closed. I tried your id and code too. No error in console.

Comment: My code had a mistake. closest function was receiving 'modal' instead of '.modal'. Please try again.

Comment: Ok, How to hide a modal and redirect to PHP file on the click of a hyperlink? Could you please correct your code accordingly as well?

Comment: What does you mean by "redirect to PHP file"? Do you want to submit some information to server when click is made? If so, you can use Ajax call to submit that information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99830/discussion-between-user2839497-and-cristiano-alencar).

Answer (score 1):

Both modal have same ids. Change the id of second modal(ex.myModal-event-2).

Then try the following code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.list-group-item').click(function(){
    $('#myModal-event').modal('hide');
    $('#myModal-event-2').modal('show');
  });
});
```

Comment: still it's not working. No error in console too. I want to get it close only on click of Edit Event menu.

Comment: Have you changed the id of second modal. Id should be unique

Comment: Yes, I do but same is the result. The modal is not getting hide.

Comment: Try  $('#myModal-event').css('display','none');

Answer (score 0):

To close a modal dialog, the corresponding button/link needs the `data-dismiss` attribute.

Replace

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
```

With

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-dismiss="modal">Edit Event</a>
```

(where `"modal"` is the id of your modal dialog)

Comment: Ok, How to dismiss a modal and redirect to PHP file on the click of a hyperlink? Could you please correct your code accordingly as well?